# CoinMarketCap API to Angular request

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, api, coinmarketcap

I have my head in water with the new [CoinMarketCap API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/).

Below is an example of a request in Node. How can I make a request in Angular?
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

```
 /* Example in Node.js ES6 using request-promise, concepts should translate 
 to your language of choice */

 const rp = require('request-promise');
 const requestOptions = {
 method: 'GET',
 uri: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest',
 qs: {
   start: 1,
   limit: 5000,
   convert: 'USD'
 },
 headers: {
  'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'API_KEY_HERE'
 },
 json: true,
 gzip: true
};

rp(requestOptions).then(response => {
  console.log('API call response:', response);
}).catch((err) => {
 console.log('API call error:', err.message);
});
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) of Angular?

Comment: I know HttpClient, but I'm blocked with this new API, and I don't know how to add the header to the request.

Comment: What do you mean with new API? The HttpClient?

Comment: The CoinMarketCap API has recently changed the way AJAX requests are made. Now it is necessary to have a key(I have)and add parameters to the call as in the example above.

Comment: I do hope the api key in your post is not your actual api key...

Comment: No, the api key is from the default example.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation found [here](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/) you cannot perform this HTTP call from a web client:

> Making HTTP requests on the client side with Javascript is currently prohibited through CORS configuration. This is to protect your API Key which should not be visible to users of your application so your API Key is not stolen. Secure your API Key by routing calls through your own backend service.

A solution would be to create your own back-end API. This API can then perform the HTTP call to `Coinmarketcap`. Your website then communicates with your custom made back-end API.

Answer (score 0):

```
    getAllCoinsListing() {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY':  'API_KEY_HERE'
      })
    };
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl, httpOptions);
    }
```